# What is the "th", "python", "python3", "java", etc... used in front a command to run a script, called?

Tags: java, python, lua, torch

In Lua with Torch, you use "th" to run a Lua script. In Python, you use either "python" or "python3" to run a python script. In Java, you use "java" to run a java class script.

What is this word in front the commands, actually called? I tried to search for the name myself, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: It's an [Interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing))

Comment: Well, it's a shell command, but also a java.exe file on your computer that's been installed in your path.  The exe file takes arguments like "-cp. MyClass.class" or "-jar MyJar.jar" and does stuff with them.  In this case, it's usually an interpreter (or also a compiler) that executes for example byte codes, or even just parses strings and runs them if you're not using a byte-code type compiler.

Comment: When would it be a compiler, and not an interpreter?

Comment: @ProGamerGov the command would be a compiler when you compile source code into an executable file. For example, the `javac` would be the command to compile a `.java` file into a bytecode. Then the `java` command executes the compiled file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a shell command. Not any different from `cd` or `grep`, etc.

In the case of Python, the `python` command invokes the Python interpreter, starting either an interactive session, or, if a file is specified, running the file through the interpreter. But it just tells the shell something to do.